# Disable Glib event loop in Qt - QT_NO_GLIB not taking effect

Tags: c++, qt, valgrind, glib

When I run the thread checking tool helgrind (valgrind toolsuite) I see a lot of errors in the glib library. I want to suppress those.

A suppression file is one option. But I found: [How to use helgrind to debug multithreaded Qt applications](http://www.kdab.com/~dfaure/helgrind.html). It suggests that I can set the QT_NO_GLIB enviroment variable to 1 to prevent Qt from using Glib.

Tried...

```
$ export QT_NO_GLIB=1
$ valgrind --tool=helgrind --log-file=helgrind.log ./app
$ grep -o 'g_[_a-z]*' helgrind.log    
g_main_context_dispatch
g_main_loop_run
g_mutex_init
g_mutex_lock
g_object_new
...
$ env | grep QT_NO_GLIB
QT_NO_GLIB=1
```

.. But the helgrind log contains many references to Glib functions. How can I set the QT_NO_GLIB enviroment variable? I'm runnning Ubuntu 13.04, using Qt 4.8.3.

Comment: Are you sure this a bash variable and not a define/globak you need to set at compile time?

Comment: @drahnr The env var is checked in [qcoreapplication.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp#line502)

Comment: That shows it is both evaluated on compile (and if enabled) also at runtime.
Are you sure this arises from the EventDispatcher and not from somewhere else?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference `QT_NO_GLIB=1 valgrind --tool=helgrind --log-file=helgrind.log ./app` https://wiki.gnome.org/Valgrind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Glib calls that you are seeing definitely don't come from Qt proper. You can verify that by git cloning Qt4.x source code from http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt.git/ and then grep for "g_main_context_dispatch". You will find nothing. This means that Glib calls come from some 3rd party plugins or other dependencies of your binary.

Using "export QT_NO_GLIB=1" to disable Glib event dispatcher is correct.